# keyboard hook as a windows service

Tags: c#, windows

Hi What i am trying is to create a application in c# which hooks all button clicks but i want  this application to be run before user logon. (so it should hook all user actions and i can get account password my parents set).
what i found out is that if i want to run something before logon it should be service so i have crated one. then i read this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

sample program works fine (captures all hooks even if app is minimized ) when it is lunched manually but without windows form it is not working. so when i trued make it without windows form i failed. When lunching it as service it is not able to display windows form (I dont want t to create interactive service ) so my app is not working. 
is it available to create an app which does not need windows form or run this form hidden or something like that and run it before logon?

P.s i am using windows 7 .

Comment: It's impossible to prevent exactly this kind of attack.

Comment: So you're asking how to make a keylogger? Nice...

Answer (score 2):

In windows 7 service cannot interact with user desktop. So it is impossible.

It is for security reasons, exactly this what you are describing.

Comment: Not exactly, [shatter attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack) are the reason.